# minimal edge representation of simple paths between all pairs of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, set, traversal, combinatorics

Honestly this doesn't seem as much of a graph type problem as it is a combinatoric/algorithm type question - but I did not know how to title it.

The situation is this:  I have a collection of nodes, which is a subset of all of the nodes of my undirected graph.  Let's say my graph is made up of nodes [0..20].  My collection of nodes is [0,1,2,3,4,5].

My graph is not complete, we don't know what edges it has until the algorithm is ran.

What I am doing, is finding all of the simple paths that go through all of the nodes in the collection, but the paths must START from a node that has an edge *out* of the collection, and END at a node that has an edge *out* of the collection.

Depending on how many edges the nodes of my collection have that go to each other node in the collection, I may end up with many many paths that connect to the two same end nodes.  (0,1,2,3,4,5), (0,2,3,1,4,5), (0,3,4,2,1,5)... etc

What I would like to do, is given a collection of paths for each *pair* of end nodes.. (0,1), (1,3), (2,4), (0,4), (2,5) .... etc, I want to find a minimal set of edges that can be used to form at least one of these paths between any two pairs of end nodes.  So, it may be the case that this minimal set needs *every* edge between the nodes of the collection, but it may also be the case that it needs much fewer than that.

This is a lot to take in, I know.  It seems very difficult.  My brain tells me this is a set intersection problem and there may not be an easy answer, but I do know that I need help even approaching it.

Comment: Do you need *the* minimal set of edges, or is it good enough to find a reasonably small set of edges?

Comment: It feels like a tradeoff between speed and precision.  If there is no polynomial time method to find the minimal set of edges, then it's probably more efficient to find a reasonably small set of edges.  The most important thing is that I am able to eliminate edges from within the collection at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is called a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) for the given graph.

[Deleted explanation of simple spanning tree algorithm]

**UPDATE PER OP CLARIFICATION**

For every pair of nodes in the graph, we need to have at least *one* path that includes every node without visiting any node a second time.  This is a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).

I concur that this is a set-driven problem: each pair of nodes will have an associated set of Hamiltonian paths (HPs).  Each path is defined by a sequence of edges.  We can represent these as a *set* of edges: we need all of the edges to form the path, so the order doesn't matter.

Finding all of the Hamiltonian paths is (relatively) easy, if tedious.

Write a recursive routine to find all HPs, given a set of nodes `all`, a set of starting nodes `s`, and a set of ending nodes `e`.  I don't think this is polynomial time; at best, I think it's `len(e)!`.  However, memoizing (dynamic programming) should be able to reduce this to something tractable, perhaps polynomial.

```
function find_paths(all, s, e)
    paths = <empty>
    if |all| == 2   // base case: no intermediate nodes
        for (start, end) in s x e
            if (start, end) has an edge
                add that edge to paths

    else if |all| == 3  // base case: only one intermediate node
        inter = all - start - end  // identify the remaining node
        for (start, end) in s x e
            if (start, inter) and (inter, end) have edges
                add that edge pair to paths

    else // recursion case
         // for each (start, end) pair, remove those from the graph,
         //   and find all intermediate paths in the remaining nodes.
        for (start, end) in s x e
            all_prime = all - start - end
            s_prime = all nodes with an edge to start
            e_prime = all nodes with an edge to end
            hp_prime = find_paths(all_prime, s_prime, e_prime)
            for each inner_path in hp_prime
                // grab the endpoints; link them to (start, end)
                path_start = inner_path[0][0]
                path_end   = inner_path[len(inner_path)-1][1]
                add ((start, path_start), inner_path, (path_end, end)) to path
        return path
```

Calling this with each pair of nodes, obtains all Hamiltonian paths in the graph, indexed by the node pair.  Reduce each path to a set of edges.  For instance, a fully-connected graph of degree four would now look like this, using `eij` (with ii and `j`.

```
(0, 1) [{e02, e23, e13}, {e03, e23, e12})
(0, 2) [{e01, e13, e23}, {e03, e13, e12})
...
(2, 3) [{e12, e01, e03}, {e02, e01, e13})
```

Now, to find a smaller tree, prioritize edge removals in any fashion you like.  For the optimal solution, try all `|E|!` orders by recursion.  From here, it's simple-but-tedious again

```
if any node-pair has no path, FAIL
put all edges into the priority_list
iterate through the node-pair sets
    if any pair has only one set (path),
        remove all the edges in that path from priority_list
prioritize the list in any fashion desired
while priority_list isn't empty
    victim = priority_list.pop()
    remove each path including victim.
    if this results in a node-pair's list having only one remaining path,
        remove all edges in that path from the priority_list

return the remaining priority_list as a sort-of-minimal set
```

Comment: A minimal spanning tree won't work, because I am looking for simple paths (paths that touch every node in the collection without going through a node twice).

Comment: Ah.  In that case, what you need is a Hamiltonian cycle?  Maybe not: if the endpoints are A and Z, you want to visit each of the *other* nodes in between, without getting to Z too early.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes.  What I actually am doing right now is a BFS of all paths between the nodes in the collection (not the graph).

Then, any of those paths that start and end on a node that has an outward edge, I save that path.

The problem is, this leaves me with way more paths (an thus, edges), than I actually need to solve this problem.